# JPA RollbackException persist transaction causes subsequent valid transactions to fail?

Tags: java, exception, jpa, transactions

I have a @Transactional service performing a persist action into an oracle DB.  If i run a persist breaking a unique violation i get the expected rollbackException:ConstraintException.

The problem is that any subsequent request (even if not breaking the unique constraint) to persist throws the same exception.

It seems like JPA is not clearing the object to persist out of its transaction manager? Am i even close?  I need a little explaination.

Repo:

```
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    public User findUserById(long id){
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);

        Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);

        Predicate whereClause = builder.equal(root.get(User_.userId), id);

        return em.createQuery(query.where(whereClause)).getSingleResult();
    }

    public User findUserByCredentials(String credentials){

        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);

        Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);

        Predicate whereClause = builder.equal(root.get(User_.credentials), credentials);

        return em.createQuery(query.where(whereClause)).getSingleResult();
    }

    public void registerUser(User user){
         em.persist(user);
    }
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Resource
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User findUserById(long id) {
        return userRepository.findUserById(id);
    }

    public User findUserByCredentials(String credentials){
        return userRepository.findUserByCredentials(credentials);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void registerUser(User user){
        userRepository.registerUser(user);
    }

}
```

error throw in endpoint:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart="RegisterUserRequest", namespace = "http://www.missingwire.com/schemas/User")
public RegisterUserResponseDocument registerUser(RegisterUserRequestDocument requestDoc){


    RegisterUserRequest request = requestDoc.getRegisterUserRequest();
    User user = new User();
    user.setCredentials(request.getCredentials());
    user.setPassword(request.getPassword());
    user.setHonorRating(BigDecimal.valueOf(STARTING_USER_HONOR_RATING));
    user.setAccountActive(true);
    user.setDateCreated(new Date());
    user.setVerified(false);

    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
    userProfile.setEmailAddress(request.getEmail());
    userProfile.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
    userProfile.setLastName(request.getLastName());
    userProfile.setDateCreated(new Date());
    userProfile.setUser(user);
    user.setUserProfile(userProfile);

    **userService.registerUser(user);**  //HERE IS THE EXCEPTION THROW

    RegisterUserResponseDocument responseDoc = RegisterUserResponseDocument.Factory.newInstance();
    RegisterUserResponse response = responseDoc.addNewRegisterUserResponse();
    UserType userType = response.addNewUser();
    userType.setAccountActive(user.getAccountActive());
    userType.setCredentials(user.getCredentials());
    userType.setDateCreated(DateConverter.convertDateToXML(user.getDateCreated()));
    userType.setUserId(user.getUserId());
    userType.setVerified(user.getVerified());

    return responseDoc;

}
```

Exception:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error while committing
>   the transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.convertException(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:501)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.afterCommit(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:481)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:953)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:796)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>     at $Proxy37.registerUser(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.missingwire.achieve.soa.endpoint.UserEndpoint.registerUser(UserEndpoint.java:76)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)     at
>   org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(MarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:93)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.afterCommit(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:478)
>     ... 39 more Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not
>   execute JDBC batch update     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:81)
>     ... 40 more Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not
>   execute JDBC batch update     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2395)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2858)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:178)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)  at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)     at
>   org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
>     ... 40 more Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001:
>   unique constraint (ACHIEVE.SYS_C0016488) violated
>
> at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10070)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)

Comment: That doesn't sound right. How far up the call stack is your request being rolled back before you make another request (that breaks). Are you using container managed transactions?

Comment: requests are sent using soap and spring but i do them 30 seconds apart.  And i can see the exception in the log.  If you need me to post code let me know.

Comment: Yes, please do add the code to your question.

Comment: ok let me know if you need more

Comment: Posted code looks fine - whats the constraint violation firing off of? Definitely not the ID. Please add entity definition for User, and the exception you're getting.

Comment: the constrain is on the credentials column and it is just a uniqueness constraint

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20371/discussion-between-perception-and-matt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're injecting an entity manager for an extended persistence context. That means that the lifetime of the persistence context is not tied to the lifetime of the transaction: it stays open until you close it explicitely.

Since you got a RollbackException, the persistence context is in a dirty, inconsistent state, and the only thing you can do is close it immediately.

If the persistence context was a transactional one, it would be closed automatically. But since you're using an extended context, it's up to you to close it explicitely.

Make sure to read and understand the following section of the Spring documentation:

> The @PersistenceContext annotation has an optional attribute type,
>   which defaults to PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION. This default is
>   what you need to receive a shared EntityManager proxy. The
>   alternative, PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED, is a completely
>   different affair: This results in a so-called extended EntityManager,
>   which is not thread-safe and hence must not be used in a concurrently
>   accessed component such as a Spring-managed singleton bean. Extended
>   EntityManagers are only supposed to be used in stateful components
>   that, for example, reside in a session, with the lifecycle of the
>   EntityManager not tied to a current transaction but rather being
>   completely up to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

To methods you want to exclude transactionallity (queries, for example), you'll avoid this problem.