# How do I troubleshoot a "javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction"?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x

I’m using `Spring 3.1.4.RELEASE`, `Hibernate 4.1.0.Final`, `JPA 2`, `JBoss 7.1.3.AS` and `MySQL 5.5.37`.  Sometimes when we try and commit a transaction, it fails, although what is annoying is rolling back fails, so there is this lock in the system that never goes away and causes other things to fail.  The rollback exception stack trace is

```
05:00:07,751 ERROR [org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.OrganizationServiceImpl] (org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-4) Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) [spring-orm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:387) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) [spring-tx-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.save(Unknown Source)
            at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.updateAllOrgRecords(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:282) [pd-60.0.0.jar:]
            at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.updateAllDistricts(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:219) [pd-60.0.0.jar:]
            at org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.updateOrgInfo(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:190) [pd-60.0.0.jar:]
            at org.mainco.subco.myproject.quartz.ProcessOrgsWorker.work(ProcessOrgsWorker.java:35) [classes:]
            at org.mainco.subco.myproject.quartz.ProcessOrgsJob.execute(ProcessOrgsJob.java:17) [classes:]
            at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) [quartz-1.8.5.jar:]
            at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549) [quartz-1.8.5.jar:]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
            at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:90) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512) [spring-orm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
            ... 14 more
    Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=eodbId, rootBeanClass=class org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message}'}
]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:184) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1127) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:325) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175) [hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.0.Final.jar:4.1.0.Final]
            ... 15 more
```

My question is how can I prevent RollBackExceptions?  Below is my configuration in Spring

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.myproject.subco" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

    <util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior" value="convertToNull" />
    </util:map>

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

**Note:** my question is NOT how do I solve my transaction exceptions in general. I would like to build something flexible enough that if there is a commit problem, things can rollback normally.

Comment: Could you post the Organization code and its validation? Seems you are trying to save/update data that fails about some specific validation constraint(**propertyPath=eodbId**) and therefore you are receiving the respective **ConstraintViolationException**

Comment: The ConstraintViolationException should not cause a RollbackException, should it?  As I said, I want to prepare for the fact that sometimes ConstraintViolations could come up, but I still want to be able to roll back transactions gracefully.  My question is, why can't I?

Comment: Yes, an exception should start the rollback process. "My question is how can I prevent RollBackExceptions?" If you want avoid a rollback for a specific exception: you can use the Transactional's noRollbackFor attribute. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

Comment: I am curious if you are using PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED annotation on your EntityManager anywhere as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13648111/1990536

Comment: Raj, no I'm not using that.  I hook up my entity manager within my DAO using @Autowired (the bean definition of the EntityManager is above).  Manuel Jordan, I don't want to prevent a rollback, just a RollbackException.  It is possible to roll back without throwing an exception, right?